# Replace one particular occurence of a substring in a string

Tags: java, android, string

I am providing facilites to make selected text **B** and *I* and etc basic formatting options in my small android project.

I need to change selected text with the chosen formatting option but what happens is that my function replaces all of the occurrences of selected substring with replacement text.

Here's my function for one of the formatting options :

```
//Make selectedText bold
bold.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Gets selection text's start and end position
            int startSelection = etText.getSelectionStart();
            int endSelection = etText.getSelectionEnd();

            text = String.valueOf((new SpannableString(etText.getText())));

            /*This is just to make sure selected string does not end up with 
              negative length */                 
            if (startSelection > endSelection) {
                startSelection = etText.getSelectionEnd();
                endSelection = etText.getSelectionStart();
            }

            //Stores the text selected by user in a string.
            String selectedText = etText.getText().toString().substring(startSelection, endSelection);

            if (!selectedText.isEmpty()) {
                /*Here selectedText is replaced with formattedText using replace function which maybe causing the replacement of all occurrences in text.*/
                text = text.replace(selectedText, "<b>" + selectedText + "</b>");
                etText.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
            }
        }
    });
```

Please i need a function (Inbuilt or User-defined) which replaces ONLY ONE occurrence of matching substring in a string instead of all.

*It will be also helpful to me if one can provide me ready code for basic text formatting in android if available.*

Comment: Did you look at the Javadoc for the `String` class, to see if there's a method called `replaceFirst` or anything like that?

Comment: To replace the first occurrence you can use `String#replaceFirst` as mentioned by @DawoodibnKareem. If you want to replace something else (e.g. third occurrence) you can play around with regular expressions using `String#replaceAll(String, String)` (and choose a regular expression that matches whatever is desired).

Comment: yes , i read about that replaceAll() method and regular expression , but i dont understand how regular expression work or how to use it in my case. can you please provide code if you can solve this using replaceAll() and regex? it would be very useful to me.

Comment: @V.Tank check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think ReplaceFirst will replace the first occurrence.

If the selected SubString is not the first, then it will not work,

I think it is better to use,

```
text = text.substring(0,startSelection-1)+"<b>" + selectedText + "</b>"+text.substring(endSelection,text.length());
```

Hope it will work:)

Comment: Yes , this totally worked for me thank you very much :))